# Any method in loopback 4 repository to update specified attributes of a record

Tags: loopback4

I want to update the user name, address, contact# of a certain user without updating the password and other attributes of a object/record.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it with following way:-

```
this.userRepository.updateById(id, member);
```

where member is Member type object.

```
const member: Partial<Member> = {
  name: 'Test Name'
}
```